# When using useEffect hook, react seems to unmount on every tick of a timer versus when using classes

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have two counters: one written with a React class and another with a React function/hook. Trying to teach myself the ins and outs of hooks but getting some weird behavior. The hook-based counter will call the destructor on every tick of the counter if I put both isOn (a state var to state whether to count or not) as well as curValue (current counter value) in the useEffect dependencies. Why is there this constant cleanup? I thought the cleanup is only fired when the component is destroyed.

If I just have isOn as a dependency it doesn't do this. Tutorials that I used suggested to add both as a dependency but I don't understand you'd need to have curValue as a dependency.

Code below:

```
//a counter that every second increments by 'props.increment' amount
function HookCounter(props) {
    const [curValue, setCounter] = useState(0);
    const [isOn, setIsOn] = useState(true);

    function toggleTimer() {
        setIsOn(!isOn);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        let _timer = null;

        function _update(x,y) {
            setCounter((current) => current + parseInt(props.increment));
        }

        if(isOn) {
            _timer = setInterval(
                _update,
                1000
            );  
        } else {
            clearInterval(_timer);
        }
        
        return () => {
            console.log('componentWillUnmount');
            clearInterval(_timer);
        };
    }, [isOn]); //if I add curValue, it calls the destructor (two lines above) every tick of the timer 

    let buttonLabel = "Start";
    if(isOn) {
        buttonLabel = "Stop";
    }

    return <div>HookCounter {curValue}  
    <button onClick={toggleTimer}>{buttonLabel}</button></div>;
}


class Counter extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.incAmount = parseInt(props.increment);
        this.state = {curValue: 0, isOn: false};

        this.toggleTimer = this.toggleTimer.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.startTimer();
    }

    startTimer() {
        this.setState({isOn: true});
        this._timer = setInterval(
            () => this.tick(),
            1000
        );
    }

    stopTimer() {
        if(this.state.isOn) {
            clearInterval(this._timer);
        }
        this.setState({isOn: false});
    }

    tick() {
        this.setState((state, props) => 
        ({
            curValue: (this.incAmount + state.curValue)
        }));
    }
  
    componentWillUnmount() {
        console.log("componentWillUnmount");
        this.stopTimer();
    }

    toggleTimer(x, y) {
        if(this.state.isOn) {
            this.stopTimer();
        } else {
            this.startTimer();
        }
    }

    render() {
        let buttonLabel = "Start";
        if(this.state.isOn)
            buttonLabel = "Stop";

        return <div>{this.state.curValue} <button onClick={this.toggleTimer}>{buttonLabel}</button></div>;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

this line right here

```js
        return () => {
            console.log('componentWillUnmount');
            clearInterval(_timer);
        };
```

does not ummount the component.

here's the code execution:

the first time that `useEffect` is called it does not execute the clean up function. when one of its parameter is changed (`isOn`) that's the time the cleanup function is executed with old value of `isOn`, then the `useEffect` function is executed again with new value of `isOn`.

to simulate `componentDidMount` and `componentWillUnmount`, you need to have empty array parameter to `useEffect`

```js
useEffect(() => {
// componentDidMount

return () => {
   // componentWillUnmount
}
}, [])
```

Answer (score 1):

**It's expected behaviour from Reactjs [Doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#example-using-hooks-1)**

> **When exactly does React clean up an effect?** React performs the cleanup when the component unmounts. However, as we learned earlier, effects run for every render and not just once. This is why React also cleans up effects from the previous render before running the effects next time. We’ll discuss why this helps avoid bugs and how to opt-out of this behavior in case it creates performance issues later below.

So basically, the `clean-up` function will run for `every render`, this is for cleaning up from previous effects.